# Hello again, Barlow Lenses

Tags: observational-astronomy

I am debating if I should buy a 2x Barlow Lens. My telescope, a go-to Meade star navigator, has an aperture of 114mm, focal length of 1000mm and I currently have a 9 and 26mm eyepieces. I want to see Jupiter and Saturn better specifically, but I wonder if such a lens is worth it.

Comment: It will be like adding 13mm and 4.5 mm oculars to your collection, so can be a good value.  4.5 mm ocular is about the maximum magnification that is useful for your telescope.

Comment: different but related Barlow question: [Which Barlow lens should I choose, 2x or 3x?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36341/7982)