# Which Barlow lens should I choose, 2x or 3x?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing

I recently bought a 6-inch reflector, 750 mm focal length and I want to get a Barlow lens to get better observations. I have 2 eyepieces, one 9mm and one 25mm.

My question is:

> Should I go for a 2x Barlow with the 9 mm eyepiece (167x magnification) or 3x with the 9 mm (250x magnification)?

I know that a 6 inch can handle about 300x. Is the 3x Barlow too much or is it suitable for what I currently have?

Comment: different but related Barlow question: [Hello again, Barlow Lenses](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36221/7982)

Comment: What are you observing? For what do you need such great magnification?